# Contact Form on website not working (Vercel and Sendgrid)

Tags: javascript, html, sendgrid, vercel, contact-form

I have a website hosted on Vercel and am trying to use Sendgrid to send emails from my contact form on the site to my gmail address. I keep getting a 405 error. From what I gather, Vercel recommends using a 3rd party to send emails, that is why I'm trying to work with sendgrid. This code was an example from Twilio but I'm not using Twilio, so I tried to edit it to be a regular JS function.

I've tried editing the code, but nothing seems to work. Here is my HTML code on my contact page with JS script. I've listed the function below that is called in the onsubmit attribute

```
<script>
  import sendMail from 'send-mail.js'
  const form = document.getElementById("contact-form");
const fromInput = document.getElementById("from");
const subjectInput = document.getElementById("subject");
const contentInput = document.getElementById("content");
const sendButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");
const status = document.getElementById("status");

function setStatus(message, class) {
  status.textContent = message;
  status.classList.add(class);
  status.removeAttribute("hidden");
}
function hideStatus() {
  status.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
  status.className = "status";
  status.textContent = "";
}
  // Listen for the submit event of the form and handle it
form.addEventListener("submit", async (event) => {
// Stop the form from actually submitting
event.preventDefault();
// Disable the submit button to avoid double submissions
sendButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
// Hide any status message as we are now dealing with a new submission
hideStatus();
try {
  // Submit the data to our function, using the action and method from the form element itself.
  const response = await fetch(form.getAttribute("action"), {
    method: form.getAttribute("method"),
    // Collect the data from the form inputs and serialize the data as JSON
    body: JSON.stringify({
      from: fromInput.value,
      subject: subjectInput.value,
      content: contentInput.value,
    }),
    // Set the content type of our request to application/json so the function knows how to parse the data
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  if (response.ok) {
    // If the response was a success, clear the form inputs and set a success message in the status
    fromInput.value = "";
    subjectInput.value = "";
    contentInput.value = "";
    setStatus("Message sent successfully. Thank you!", "success");
    // After 5 seconds, hide the success message.
    setTimeout(hideStatus, 5000);
  } else {
    // If the request returns an error response, read the error message from the response and set it as a failure message in the status
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    setStatus(data.error, "error");
  }
  // The request is over, so enable the submit button again
  sendButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
} catch (error) {
  // If the request failed, set a generic error message in the status
  setStatus(
    "There was an error and the message could not be sent. Sorry.",
    "error"
  );
  console.log(error);
  // The request is over, so enable the submit button again
  sendButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
}
});

</script>
```

```
const sg = require("@sendgrid/mail");

export const sendMail = async function(context, event, callback) {
  sg.setApiKey(context.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  const msg = {
    to: "******MY EMAIL WAS HERE******",
    from: { email: context.FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS, name: "Your contact form" },
    replyTo: event.from,
    subject: `[contactform] ${event.subject}`,
    text: `New email from ${event.from}.\n\n${event.content}`,
  };
  try {
    await sg.send(msg);
    response.setStatusCode(200);
    response.setBody({ success: true });
    return callback(null, response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    let { message } = error;
    if (error.response) {
      console.error(error.response.body);
      message = error.response.body.errors[0];
    }

    response.setStatusCode(400);
    response.setBody({ success: false, error: message });
    return callback(null, errorResponse(response, message));
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems you try to import `send-email.js` in the browser. This is probably the reason why it doesn't work and I would strongly recommend against doing so because it would expose your credentials to all clients/browser. Instead, you could use NextJS (or another framework) to move this code to the backend.